# pycharm - plot closes immediately

Tags: pycharm

i am new to pycharm and have a simple problem. I am trying to plot, a figure appears but closes immediately with the end of the program.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(X,y)
fig.show()
```

in another question the answer to a similar problem was setting.

```
plt.show(block=True)
```

but this did not work, with the error "keyword argument block does not exist".

Thanks for your help

best regards
Leo

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem it got fixed with the one u saw but u can try `plt.show(block=False)`
or

```
plt.show(block=True)
plt.close()
```